# Log data, not only string (Python)

Tags: python

I want to log data, not just string in a python.

I would like to avoid implementing this myself, since I think this was done before.

I want to support these primitive data types:

- strings
- integers
- datetime
- lists
- dictionaries

Putting above into a log is easy.

I need the next part too: Parse the logs to data again.

I don't care if the data format is json, xml, yaml, protcol buffers or something else.

The library should be open source.

Answer (score 0):

There is [structlog](http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/)

The web page says this:

> structlog makes logging in Python less painful and more powerful by adding structure to your log entries.

But I have not used it up to now.